# How to create an application shortcut with additional parameters on Mac OS

Tags: macos, file-shortcut

I'm trying to create an application shortcut on Mac OS (Monterey), which is as similar as possible to a normal app shortcut, but the solution I've come up with isn't really elegant and not very practical either.
What I'm trying to do is to start Firefox with a certain profile, so I need to add `-P <profile-name>` to it.
What I've done so far is to create a file called `Firefox-profile.command` as a shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
nohup /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -P <profile_name> &
exit
```

There are two issues with this one:

- It starts the terminal app which doesn't close afterwards (only the window that started the app closes - after setting "Close if the shell exited cleanly"). This wouldn't have bothered me normally, but I use iterm2, not terminal.
- Secondly, I cannot create a shortcut in the dock. It simply ignores it. Changing the extension to .app does allow me to create the shortcut, but then it doesn't work at all anymore, because it expects a different format and it asks me about an app I should be open the file with.
  I also don't want to place the shortcut in the right pane of docker (which works), I want to choose the position myself within the main pane :)

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

idk if you can do this from a terminal, but you can do it by Applescript, then save it as an app.
You need something along these lines…

```
do shell script "\"/Applications/AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName\" -parameter1 -parameter2 data data"
```

Save as an Application; set to not show splash screen & not stay open. You will need to give it permissions first time you launch it. Done this way it will actually stay open all the time the process it launched is open, then will quit when you manually quit that process.

Comment: Indeed, it stays open. But at least I can use it as a proper shortcut in the dock. So there's a little progress in that :)